# Special chars inside .policy file for PolicyKit action

Tags: xml, special-characters, policy

I'm trying to use special characters (the ones that should start with an ampersand '&' and finish with semicolon ';') but I can't make it work. It only outputs the part after the ampersand. (eg: ' some text there')

This is part of the `.policy` file I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <vendor>Some text here &amp; some text there</vendor>
  <vendor_url>http://example.com/</vendor_url>

  <action id="...">
    ...
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

Is there another way of encoding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with PolicyKit.

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88420